# Postgres PITR: Recovery does not seem to fetch from Archive Dir

Tags: postgresql

Make and give permission to database dir

```
cd /home/admin-12/Desktop/

mkdir test2
sudo chown postgres:postgres test2

mkdir test2_wal
sudo chown postgres:postgres test2_wal

touch test2.log
sudo chown postgres:postgres test2.log
```

Init Database

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/initdb -D /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2
```

Edit postgres conf

```
nano /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2/postgresql.conf

archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2_wal/%f'

/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2 -l /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2.log start
```

Dummy Data

```
create table testPITR1 as select * from pg_class, pg_description; 
select * from current_timestamp;
```

Backup

```
SELECT pg_start_backup('label', false, false);
tar -cvzf test2.tar test2
SELECT * FROM pg_stop_backup(false, true);
```

More Dummy data

```
create table testPITR2, testPITR3, testPITR4
```

Kill existing db

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2 -l /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2.log stop
mv test2 test2.bad
tar -xvzf test2.tar 
sudo chown -R postgres:postgres test2
```

Recovery conf

```
nano /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2/recovery.conf

restore_command = 'cp /home/admin-12/Desktop/test2_wal/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2019-08-21 16:14:11.175781+05:30'
```

**WITHOUT THIS STEP I CANNOT RECOVER Table 2,3,..**

```
cp test2.bad/pg_wal/0* test2/pg_wal/
```

Any tips?

---

IF i do above steps in Postgres Docker (using volumes), then I get `PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record`, but this somehow is limited to docker

Comment: When you are not using docker, what error do you get? Look into "/home/admin-12/Desktop/test2_wal/", what is there?

Comment: files are getting populated in `test2_wal` folder. similar to naming of wal files.

Comment: I think there was something else wrong at my end, tried to do it a couple more times. now it seems to be working fine. weird. Thanks for the help. I think i must have rebooted the postgres before doing restore, that might have confused its recovery process?

Comment: for docker, I had to go inside docker and do `chown -R postgres:postgres`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that WAL files only get archived when they are full (or at the end of a PostgreSQL backup).

So it is likely that there was no WAL switch since you finished the backup, and the WAL archiver probably died before it could archive the final WAL file with the additional actions in it (check the original server's log file).

You can use the `archive_timeout` parameter to mitigate the problem, or you can use `pg_receivewal` to archive WAL in real time, so you don't lose transactions.

The error from your docker container indicates that the `restore_command` didn't work (check the log file).

Comment: He did a clean shutdown, that will normally force a WAL switch and archival.

Comment: Yes, that is weird, which is why I wrote that the server log should be checked.

Comment: ok will check logs, but files are getting populated on test2_wal. A tutorial recommend to insert 1000s of records to simulate Wal archival.

Comment: Did any WAL segments get archived *after* the backup?

Comment: i'll re-try and capture these details (logs, wal-archive generation)

Comment: I think there was something else wrong at my end, tried to do it a couple more times. now it seems to be working fine. weird. Thanks for the help. I think i must have rebooted the postgres before doing restore, that might have confused its recovery process?